# getRealOneOf() vs getOneOf() in Descriptor.Descriptor Java API

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Can anyone enlighten me about the difference of getRealOneOfs and getOneOfs?

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.Descriptor.html#getOneofs--

Answer (score 1):

Every proto3 optional field is placed into a one-field oneof, called a "synthetic" oneof, as it was not present in the source .proto file. The `getOneOfs` method will return all oneofs, including synthetic ones, whereas `getRealOneOfs` will exclude the synthetic oneofs.

More info here (in the Background section):

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/implementing_proto3_presence.md